# Posting image and video attachements with a discord bot

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have the following discord bot code:

```py
            messageAttachements = []

            for attachment in message.attachments:
                messageAttachements.append(attachment.url)

            embed = Embed()
    
            for index, url in enumerate(messageAttachements, start=1):
                embed.set_image(url=url)
                embed.set_footer(text=f"Image {index}")

            await toChannel.send(embed=embed)

            await toChannel.send(f" {' '.join(messageAttachements)}")
```

message is the Message object from the discord python library, where basically I pull out all of the attachement Urls from that message and then repost them as a bot message to another channel.

The trouble is that while in the original post the images are displayed next to each other in a row, while in the bot post in the toChannel, each of the images is displayed on a separate line, which causes them to take up vertically much more space.
I also tried an embed method, which is the commented out code, but It didn't seem to work correctly, it only displayed one image.
Also the attachements reposted by the bot have this: [image] next to them, while the pictures in the original post don't have it. Which makes me believe there must be a different way to attach those file to the post with the bot.

How can I repost those attachements with the bot,  so they are displayed nicely in a row, just like in the original post?

Thank you

Comment: I think that's intended. You could use Pillow to squeeze 4 images onto one, but that's about it.

Comment: @Dominik it doesn't have to be an embed I just want multiple images to be in a row, instead of each one separate line. When you use the + icon and upload several images on your post they are all displayed in a row as well

Comment: I am not talking about an embed here. (I think) it's simply not possible with a bot to send/display it the way you want.